# WCF IsOneWay = true report Exception

Tags: wcf

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface Service
{
   [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
   void ServiceMethod();
}
```

I set server's code with `IsOneWay = true`, because the client does not care about the server's result and the server's method may need run a long time (e.g.30 mins) in some cases.

But I found the client still waits for the server's method to be finished. After the server finished in 30 mins, client requests again, report the `CommunicationException`:

> "The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:01:00'".

I think the client still wait the result (default `receiveTimeOut` is 10 mins), then lead to timeout. I use WCF 3.0.

Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-way call in WCF is not the same thing as an asynchronous call.

Even though the client making a one-way call will not receive a response from the service, if the service does not have a thread available to dispatch or queue the incoming client request then the client will hang and eventually timeout if no dispatcher thread becomes available within the timeout period.

The number of available threads and the size of the request queue are managed by WCF and are determined by the service concurrency mode, session mode, and whether the service was configured with reliable messaging, amongst other factors.

Comment: No, the available threads or size of the request queue are managed by WCF and are determined by the concurrency mode and session mode which you have set on the service, also whether the service was configured with reliable messaging or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But to be honest I'm new to WCF and not quite understand about what you said. It's my fault.Maybe I need to read something more about WCF.

Comment: Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730149.aspx. If you continue to get problems please let me know I will try to help.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN ServiceBehviorAttribute.concurrencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx) states:

> Setting ConcurrencyMode to Single instructs the system to restrict
>   instances of the service to one thread of execution at a time, which
>   frees you from dealing with threading issues.

That means that server side all calls on the service will come in on a unique thread.  Which is great as you don't have to worry about multithreading but also **not so great in that if you block that one thread with a long operation then other calls from your client that happen while its processing will not get through**.  Hence the exception.

ConcurrancyMode = Single is the default.  You could try setting the concurrancy mode to Multiple - which will mean that calls will now come in on random threadpool threads and if one of those is busy processing a request another one is available for another request.  But because the enviroment is now multithreading you will have to protect server objects from access by multiple thread with locks or other syncronisation mechanisms.

Comment: Downvoter - it's rude to downvote without commenting. Let the responder know why you think their answer is not correct.

Comment: @Hugh Thanks - I think this answer is basically correct - Im not understanding the down vote.

Comment: @Downvoter - please explain your downvote - if there is something incorrect in this answer Id like to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-generating the service client? It may be that the client still has a reference to a synchronous operation, whereas the server has been re-defined as one way / async.

Comment: Yes,I have re-generated the client code via add service reference.But it still does not work.

Comment: Ok - if you select 'Generate asynchronous operations' in Advanced when performing the Add Service Reference, you will get additional methods in your generated client code - i.e. ServiceMethodAsync().
If you call these without setting up a callback then this will prevent your client thread from blocking / WCF timeout errors.
More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx